# How can I fetch the complete main navigation menu via JSON:API?

Tags: 8

How can I fetch the complete main navigation menu via jsonapi?

I've tried:

```
curl --header 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json' https://cms.example.com/jsonapi/menu/menu/
```

and

```
 curl --header 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json' https://cms.example.com/jsonapi/menu/menu/232fc942-51f3-4478-8535-e5dc482a166e
```

where `232fc942-51f3-4478-8535-e5dc482a166e` is the `id` of the main-navigation menu BUT only the first level nodes are returned:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "menu--menu",
    "id": "232fc942-51f3-4478-8535-e5dc482a166e",
    "attributes": {
      "label": "Main navigation"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": {
    "href": "https://cms.garanteasy.com/jsonapi/menu/menu/232fc942-51f3-4478-8535-e5dc482a166e"
      }
    }
  },
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "meta": {
      "links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/"
    }
      }
    }
  },
  "links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://cms.garanteasy.com/jsonapi/menu/menu/232fc942-51f3-4478-8535-e5dc482a166e"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's confusing, but instead of looking for _menus_ you need to look for _menu_link_content_. g.rocchini posted in [issue #3012062, comment #6](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi/issues/3012062#comment-12847525) a few days ago about this very thing. Unfortunately you need to filter on your own based on the menu name after getting _all_ of the menu link content.

Answer (score 2):

I did not get it to run with JSON:API, there are several long-standing issues...

*However* you can get it to run if you additionally install the [REST Menu Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_menu_tree) module.

Be aware that this has several direct and indirect dependencies:

It has a direct dependency on [Menu Normalizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_normalizer) and according to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_menu_tree/issues/2899998) you need to then activate that endpoint for example with the [REST UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/restui) module - which in turn will activate the [core REST module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest).

Then in your site activate the endpoint via the Rest UI in `/admin/config/services/rest`.

Afterwards you might also want to allow everyone to GET this endpoint via `/admin/people/permissions#module-rest`

And finally you get a JSON array in `/entity/menu/main/tree`.
Or query a different menu via `/entity/menu/{internal_menu_name}/tree`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to pull all the menu items using the JSON:API exclusively. The main "long standing issue" is that the links are not available to non admin users, which probably defeats the purpose for most users. There are a couple patches, however, that allow this:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2915792

And to add the url property:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3066751

This allows you to hit this endpoint:

`/jsonapi/menu_link_content/your-menu-machine-name`

And get a standard JSON:API result.

> Key takeaway: The state of Drupal's headless menu fetching is abysmal.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [rest_menu_items](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_menu_items) module. This doesn't have any dependencies, the only thing you need to do is enable the endpoint. This also enables you to specify which values you want, and specify the depth of the tree.